# How do I find duplicates within two columns in a csv file, then combine them in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, duplicates

I am working with a large dataset of protein-protein interactions, which I have in a .csv file. The first two columns are the interacting proteins, and the order does not matter (ie A/B is the same as B/A, so they are duplicates). There is also a third column, with a source for where these interactions were published. Duplicate pairs can be from the same source, or different sources.

For the duplicates that are from two or more sources, how can I combine them, then in the third column have all of the sources listed for one interaction? (i.e. for an interaction A/B, the duplicates would be A/B and B/A).

Here is an example of the columns:

```
Interactor A         Interactor B              Source
A                    B                         Mary (2005)
C                    D                         John (2004)
B                    A                         Mary (2005)
A                    B                         Steve (1993)
D                    C                         Steve (1993)
```

In this case, i would need

```
Interactor A         Interactor B              Source
A                    B                         Mary (2005), Steve (1993)
C                    D                         John (2004), Steve (1993)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could aggregate them using the **sorted** `tuple` as a dictionary key (to make `A, B` and `B, A` equivalent, tuples can be used as a dictionary key, since it's immutable and hashable - lists are not) . Use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#set) to store the aggregated values and avoid duplicates.

I'd also throw in [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to make it nicer to aggregate values:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

# ... read values using a csv reader (assuming name csv_reader)

result = defaultdict(set)
for row in csv_reader:
    # create same key for `A, B` and `B, A`
    key = tuple(sorted([row[0], row[1]]))
    result[key].add(row[2])

# result should now contain all aggregated values
```

Comment: When I try importing my csv file, it says "non keyword arg after keyword arg." currently, I'm doing `csv_reader = csv.reader('csv file', dialect = 'excel', 'rb')`.

Comment: There are countless examples of how to use the csv module, as well as an official documentation. I addressed the more interesting side of the question. I'd start by googling "python csv example", or even go through the tags `python` and `csv` here. It should get you started in no time.

Comment: Joe: Reading the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module's documentation is also a great way to learn how things are done.

Comment: Yeah, that was my bad, sorry! One last question, when I try to run this it says that `'_csv.reader' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` on line 6. Is there a way to fix this error?

Comment: Could be that I have an error somewhere. Are you using the final edit of the answer?

Comment: Just changed it to the final edit...it's working now!

Comment: @JoeSeigel you should consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Why not just use excels conditional formatting. That will give you the duplicates for rows 1 and 2 then apply a filter. The results will be obvious.